# Daily Hours Burned Status Report For All The Tasks In An Iteration: Filtering By People

Tags: rally

I am a new born baby as far as Rally is concerned.I am desperately in need of a solution for a requirement in rally Custom Page coding.

The requirement is as follows:

A report kind of page needed. This page would be run by end of everyday.

The report should have the "Hours burned by all people in a particular Iteration for all the tasks for the day"

To depict clearly, the report should have the following captions:

Name of owners    ----    Hours burned for a day   -----    Tasks

PS: When I enquired the options with the rally support team, they advised me to focus on App SDK and Web Services API for this App.

I will be more obliged if someone could give me soulution for this. I am helpless and in no mans land as the people around me are unaware about Rally.

Thank you in advance
Bharath

Comment: Please give a hint on how to start with this

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Custom Report under the Reports Tab.  Select 
Type == TimeSheet
Data == Time Spent
Broken Down by Iteration, User, and Datae
Filter == by Iteration (or you could change this for each Date).